# How to convert such example object array to string and revert it back?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have an object array like this

```
polyPaths: LatLngLiteral[] = [{lat: 12.994169219614097, lng: 77.62397007054658}
 {lat: 12.984802167360343, lng: 77.67581180638642}
 {lat: 12.957702635784846, lng: 77.65864566869111}
 {lat: 12.974765648082716, lng: 77.61538700169892}];
```

I want to show this object array as string in `textarea`

```
(12.994169219614097,77.62397007054658)
(12.984802167360343,77.67581180638642)
(12.957702635784846,77.65864566869111)
(12.974765648082716,77.61538700169892)
```

On text input change, I want string revert back to object array of `polyPaths`.

I tried with following **js** example:

```
let stringPath = this.polyPaths.map(path => {
    return '(' + path.lat + ',' + path.lng + ')';
});
var convertedPath = stringPath.join('');
this.polyControls.area.setValue(convertedPath);
```

But not able to revert it back on input change.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try the following, it's basic string/array manipulation

```js
const polyPaths = [{
  lat: 12.994169219614097,
  lng: 77.62397007054658
}, {
  lat: 12.984802167360343,
  lng: 77.67581180638642
}, {
  lat: 12.957702635784846,
  lng: 77.65864566869111
}, {
  lat: 12.974765648082716,
  lng: 77.61538700169892
}]


// converting it to a string
const convertedPath = polyPaths.map(path => `(${path.lat},${path.lng})`).join('\n');
console.log(convertedPath)


// reversing it back
const reversed = convertedPath.split('\n').map(x => {
  const [lat, lng] = x.slice(1, x.length - 1).split(",").map(Number)
  return {
    lat,
    lng
  }
})

console.log(reversed)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try like below. Explanation is in comments.

```js
let polyPaths = [{
  lat: 12.994169219614097,
  lng: 77.62397007054658
}, {
  lat: 12.984802167360343,
  lng: 77.67581180638642
}, {
  lat: 12.957702635784846,
  lng: 77.65864566869111
}, {
  lat: 12.974765648082716,
  lng: 77.61538700169892
}];

let stringPath = polyPaths.map(path => {
  return '(' + path.lat + ',' + path.lng + ')';
});

var convertedPath = stringPath.join('');
console.log(convertedPath);

// split your string with (
polyPaths = convertedPath.split('(') 
  .filter(path => path.includes(')')) // remove first entry which will be empty string
  .map(path => ({
    lat: path.split(',')[0].trim(), // get lat from each record
    lng: path.split(',')[1].replace(')', '').trim(), // get lng from each record, remove )
  }));

console.log(polyPaths);
```